# Adding to path vs. linking from /bin

Tags: symlink, path, directory-structure

Our sys admin installed a software application (Maven) on the server and told everyone to add the `/usr/local/maven/bin/` folder to their path.

I think it could be more convenient to just link the few programs in that folder from the `/bin` folder (or other folder that everyone has in their path) like this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/maven/bin/* /bin
```

Is this correct? Are there some hidden side effects to my suggestion?

Comment: Per [LSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) you should add external packages under `/opt`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### On linking

You generally do not link `/usr/local/*` with `/bin`, but this is more of a historical practice. In general, there are a few "technical" reason why you cannot do what you're suggesting.

Making links to executables in `/bin` can cause problems:

1. Probably the biggest caveat would be if you're system is having packages managed by some sort of package manager such as RPM, dpkg, APT, YUM, pacman, pkg_add, etc. In these cases, you'll generally want to let the package manager do its job and manage directories such as `/sbin`, `/bin`, `/lib`, and `/usr`. One exception would be `/usr/local` which is typically a safe place to do as you see fit on the box, without having to worry about a package manager interfering with your files.
2. Often times executables built for `/usr/local` will have this PATH hard-coded into their executables. There may also be configuration files that are included in `/usr/local` as part of the installation of these applications. So linking to just the executable could cause issues with these apps finding the `.cfg` files later one. Here's an example of such a case:

   ```
   $ strings /usr/local/bin/wit | grep '/usr/local'
   /usr/local/share/wit
   /usr/local/share/wit/
   ```
3. The same issue that applies to finding `.cfg` files can also occur with "helper" executables that the primary app needs to run. These too would also need to be linked into `/usr/bin`, knowing this might be problematic and only show up when you actually attempted to execute the linked app.

**NOTE:** in general it's best to avoid the temptation to link to one off apps in `/usr/bin`.

#### /etc/profile.d

Rather then have all the users provide this management, the admin could very easily add this to everyone's `$PATH` on the box by adding a corresponding file in the `/etc/profile.d` directory.

A file such as this, `/etc/profile.d/maven.sh`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/maven/bin
```

You generally do this as an admin instead of polluting all the users' setups with this.

#### Using alternatives

Most distros now provide another tool called `alternatives` (Fedora/CentOS) or `update-alternatives` (Debian/Ubuntu) which you can also use to loop into the `$PATH` tools which might be outside the `/bin`. Using tools such as these is preferable since these are adhering more to what most admins would consider "standard practice" and so makes the systems easier to hand off from one admin to another.

This tool does a similar thing in making links in `/bin`; but it manages the creation and destruction of these links, so it's easier to understand a system's intended setup when done through a tool vs. done directly as you're suggesting.

Here I'm using that system to manage Oracle's Java on a box:

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/ | grep " java"
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 73 Feb  5 13:15 java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.1.fc19.x86_64/jre/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 77 Feb  5 13:15 java.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/java-java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.1.fc19.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 70 Feb  5 13:19 javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.1.fc19.x86_64/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 78 Feb  5 13:19 javac.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/javac-java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.1.fc19.x86_64.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 72 Feb  5 13:19 javadoc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.1.fc19.x86_64/bin/javadoc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 80 Feb  5 13:19 javadoc.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/javadoc-java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.1.fc19.x86_64.1.gz
```

You can see the effects of this:

```
$ type java
java is /usr/bin/java

$ readlink -f /usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.4.1.fc19.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

#### My $0.02

Making links in `/bin`, though plausible, would likely be highly discouraged by most sysadmins:

1. Would be frowned upon because it's viewed as custom and can lead to confusion if another admin is required to pick up the box
2. Can lead to a system becoming broken at a future state as a result of this "fragile" customization.

Comment: @slm You might want to modify your first paragraph. There are several technical reasons not to use a symlink.

Comment: @jlliagre - in looking at your A I'm not convinced that the admins don't own the `/bin` directory. Here's an example. On Red Hat distros that utilize RPM if a file already exists in `/bin` RPM will not install on top of as you've described, unless coxed to do so using the `--replacefiles` switch. So that's not really a technical reason. Same with other directories. I understand what you're saying about the OS "owning" `/bin` but it isn't as outright as you're stating.

Comment: @jlliagre - also in my A I'm not encouraging anyone to create a link, merely stating they can if they choose to do so. I hate systems where things are done like that and typically curse the admin that's done so 8-).

Comment: @slm They can (as they have sufficient privileges) but that doesn't imply this will work. Points #2 and #3 in my answer are still valid technical reasons not to create a link but to use the correct PATH, especially in the OP case. I would encourage you to mention them in your reply.

Comment: @jlliagre - added details per your feedback.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi - please don't misunderstand me, I added those bullets to my answer to appease Jlliagre, those are minor points and my A is much better. The details that he points out (about Maven install) should've been already known by whomever was doing the setup of Maven for you. They do not say anything additional then what I already described through the use of `/etc/profile.d`. Accepting his A is mistake IMO!

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi - his 1st bullet is just wrong, as I explained in my comments here. The other bullets are reaches.

Comment: @slm The fact you found a case where the package manager won't overwrite by default a preexisting file or link present in `/bin` doesn't make my 1st bullet "wrong". For example, it is a fact the standard SVR4 package manager found at least on Solaris will silently  delete any existing symbolic link. Note also that the OP didn't state what OS he is using. You (probably rightly) assumed he is using some Linux distribution but there is no evidence he does.

Comment: @jlliagre - there are other cases where pkg managers will not overwrite, in fact looking it would seem to be more the default behavior (rightly so). Other than the one you've mentioned and the method that Slackware uses, I cannot think of a pkg mgr that will overwrite by def. `pkg_add` requires switches as does `dpkg`. But what I'm really taking issue w/ is the comment about the OS owning that dir. That bullet is overselling this as a technical reason.

Comment: I'm afraid you are too confident about Linux package managers. I just made a quick test and `dpkg` blindingly overwrote a custom link. See my updated answer.

Comment: @jlliagre - dpkg doesn't constitute Linux pkg managers, it is but one, I was going off of the fact that it has a switch called `--force-overwrite` http://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what `dpkg --force-overwrite` option does and probably what `rpm --replacefiles` does too, at least according to its documentation. Their behavior is consistent with SVR4 pkgadd and they are rightly silently overwriting a file installed by an admin that erroneously thinks he owns /bin.

Comment: @jlliagre - I repeated your same test on RPM and it too also overwrote the link, I've amended my answer to make note of this.

Comment: I think that this answer is correct but misses the point of the OP's question. As I interpreted it, he wanted to know whether there are any disadvantages to putting a symlink in some directly already in the path, as opposed to modifying the path - which this answer doesn't address at all. While it's worth mentioning that it's better to put user-defined symlinks in `/usr/local/` than in `/bin/`, I think that point should be more of a one-sentence comment than the bulk of the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Answering to the questions asked:

> Is this correct?

**No**, it is a poor practice.

> Are there some hidden side-effects to my suggestion?

**Yes** there are several side effects. Your suggestion might work or not depending on the application, and might regress or be broken in the long term.

There are sensible reasons **not** to create such a symbolic link:

- Administrators do not "own" `/bin` (see note 1) as this directory belongs to the operating system/distribution developers. On the other hand `/usr/local` is a traditional location for software built by the local administrator, `/opt/<packagename>` being one for unbundled software. If you create a file or a link in `/bin`, there is a risk for it to be overwritten by a package installation, in your case an hypothetical `maven` package provided by the OS, which might lead to a regression if the one built locally is created from newer source code that the OS version. For example, SVR4 `pkgadd` , debian `dpkg`, red-hat `rpm` and slackware tarballs will all blindingly overwrite your symbolic link.
- Some applications do look to the place where they are called to retrieve configuration files, plugins and similar resources. If you call the application by a symbolic link, its code might fail to follow it and then look for these resource files around `/usr/bin` where they are not.
- <s>There might be other binaries in `/usr/local/maven/bin` and not adding this directory to your PATH will make them unavailable.</s> Removed as you already take that into account with your command by linking all potential commands.
- The [maven2 page](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Unix-based_Operating_Systems_Linux_Solaris_and_Mac_OS_X) tells to add this directory to your PATH (precisely: ***Add M2 environment variable to your path, e.g. export PATH=$M2:$PATH***.) , by using a different approach, your are breaking that step so are going an unsupported way. Of course, if most users of a system are potential `maven` users, it would make more sense to set the `PATH` globally instead than on each and every `.profile`.

Note 1:

[Slackware documentation:](http://www.slackbook.org/html/system-configuration.html)

```
   The /bin directory usually doesn't receive modification
   after installation. If it does, it's usually in the form
   of package upgrades that we provide.
```

[Debian / Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard)

```
/bin/
   Essential command executable (binaries) for all users (e.g., cat, ls, cp) 
   (especially files required to boot or rescue the system)
...
/opt/
   Add-on application software packages 
   Pre-compiled, non ".deb" binary distribution (tar'ed..) goes here.
/opt/bin/
   Same as for top-level hierarchy
```

[Solaris documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1474/filesystem-5.html#REFMAN5filesystem-5)

```
/usr/bin
   Platform-dependent, user-invoked executables. These  are
   commands  users expect to be run as part of their normal
   $PATH. For executables that are different  on  a  64-bit
   system  than  on a 32-bit system, a wrapper that selects
   the  appropriate  executable   is   placed   here.   See
   isaexec(3C).  An approved installation location for bun-
   dled Solaris software. The analogous location for add-on
   system     software     or     for    applications    is
   /opt/packagename/bin.
```

Simple test showing Debian's `dpkg` doesn't preserve an existing link, even while the `--force-overwrite` option is not used:

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/banner
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Feb 25 21:37 /usr/bin/banner -> /tmp/banner
# dpkg -i sysvbanner_1.0.15_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package sysvbanner.
(Reading database ... 236250 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking sysvbanner (from sysvbanner_1.0.15_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up sysvbanner (1.0.15) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
# ls -l /usr/bin/banner
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11352 May  7  2009 /usr/bin/banner
```

Comment: Important indeed. It is quite unfortunate you accepted an answer that incorrectly states it is just an historical practice with no technical reasons to avoid ...

Comment: You are right, but, I accepted that answer because it gave me a practical solution that I used, which is, tell the sys admin to put the PATH modification command in  /etc/profile.d .

Comment: I agree he gave a practical and correct solution but not to the two questions you asked ("Is this correct ? Are there side effects ?").

Comment: jlliagre is fully right. This practice is not historical at all. It is rather a recent best practice. On the contrary on old Unixes everyone installed his piece of software directly in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. Upon discovering the problems of hidden or distroyed system binaries (the most famous was `test`) the best practice to install non system binaries somewhere else was progressivly adopted.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to symlink, it would be better to symlink to `/usr/local/bin`. On my server, I used to install local software into `/opt/NAME` and symlink the binaries to `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the two suggested methods is to create a shell script in `/usr/local/bin` that, when executed, executes whatever binary you specify in the script. For instance, using maven as an example, I would create a shell script in `/usr/local/bin` called `maven` that has a small script inside to execute the maven binary where it is located and pass any arguments to it:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/maven/bin/maven "$@"
```

This has the downside of having to do this for every binary you want to "link", but it allows you to call those binaries from the command line without needing to muck up your `$PATH` environment variable.