# Downgrade gcc to 4.6.3 on fedora?

Tags: fedora, yum, gcc

How can I downgrade gcc to 4.6.3 on fedora.  I am working on a project that I do not have permission to update to be comparable with 4.8 and need to be able to install gcc 4.6.3.  How can I do this?

Comment: download gcc 4.6.3 package to your home directory and setup path to it. then when you compile it will pickup gcc from your home directory instead of systems

Comment: BTW, if this has something to do with prepping stuff for Debian wheezy (who's default gcc is 4.6.3) or something derived from it, there's a 4.7 available for wheezy (`apt-cache search gcc-4.7`).  You can `export CC=gcc-4.7` and use that there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try removing the current version then re-install the wanted  version:

```
yum remove gcc 
yum install gcc-4.6.3
```

Note: you may keep both the current version and 4.6.3 version if you wish, because the binaries for them would be different: `/usr/bin/gcc-4.8` and `/usr/bin/gcc-4.6.3`

if yum did not work you have to use `make`:
first install `gcc-4.6.3.tar.gz`from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.6.3/

```
tar -xvf gcc-4.6.3.tar.gz
```

then

```
cd gcc-4.6.3/
./contrib/download_prerequisites
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc/4.6.3
```

then

```
make
make install
```

Comment: yum responds with `No package gcc-4.6.3 available.` when I try to do that.

Comment: @tylerjw, see Updates

Comment: I'm getting the error `configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH` when I try to configure it.  Should I re-install the new gcc to compile the old one?

Comment: Yes, you need a compiler in order to compile things.

Comment: @tylerjw, yes as goldilocks said you need a compiler and as I mentioned in my answer you don't have to delete the current version

Comment: @Networker, Is there a convenient way to get it to simlink all the binaries into /usr/bin?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116508/adding-to-path-vs-linking-from-bin

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain there aren't any distro builds of 4.6 for Fedora 20 (or 19, or 18, or 17).

> I am working on a project that I do not have permission to update to be comparable with 4.8 and need to be able to install gcc 4.6.3.

If this is a C project, there's no difference between what 4.6 will compile and what 4.8 will compile *unless* you stipulate `--std=c11` (or `gnu11`). Take a look:

- [Release notes 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html)
- [Release notes 4.7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html)

The same is true for C++, except it's much more likely that you would want to use `--std=c++0x` (I don't think 4.6 had `c++11`, but these amount to the same thing).  In that case, consult the [C++0x/C++11 support page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) before you make use of a given feature (e.g., `nullptr` is okay with 4.6, delegating constructors are not).

Comment: Like I said, I don't have permission to update the files that will not compile with 4.8.  Specifically my problem is with the changes made with regard to how `<sys/syscall.h>` is included.  See [forum question](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=667428) and [gcc guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/porting_to.html).

Comment: ...would seem to fall into the category of "things that were done wrong in the first place", but if your hands are tied, your hands are tied.

Comment: I'm sure that at some point it'll be fixed.  I raised the issue and was told to use the older compiler for now.